# Mysql - difference in auto increment and no. of row

Tags: mysql

the number of rows in my mysql TB (As shown in TB info) is 11093 where as the auto increment id (starting from 1) is 11361. Why is that so?

Comment: You might have deleted from or cleared the table concerned without resetting the increment id.

Comment: have you deleted any table elements

Answer (score 0):

Deleted rows do not reset the AI index. Row count is the number of entries currently in your table, while the AI value is the number of rows you ever added to the table.